# Cypress & Istanbuljs - Cannot read property 'loc' of undefined while running cypress test cases

Tags: cypress, istanbul

issue:
"Cannot read property 'loc' of undefined"
while running test cases .
all the first test case are failing because of this issue .

when issue happen :
cypress integrated with istanbuljs for code coverage on lcov format.
other format seems to be working fine.

https://github.com/istanbuljs/istanbuljs/issues/572#

Comment: In the GitHub link, I could see two work around. Have you tried them?

Comment: "nyc": {
    "reporter": [
      "html"
    ]
  } would resolve this issue but we need lcov format to support sonar kindly highlight another fix if you notice will be helpful.